# AIで顔のパーツを認識するライブラリ

Tags: アルゴリズム, 画像処理

AI系のプログラムを書いたことはなくて、大学の講義で分類器や Deep Learning の仕組みを少しかじった程度です。

やりたいことは、２次元のキャラ画像を入力に与えたときにその属性を自動抽出することです。
まずは簡単そうなところで髪色と瞳の色あたりを認識したいです。

画像を入力して顔のパーツを自動抽出するようなフリーライブラリはありますでしょうか。
顔認識はかなり研究が進んでるときいたことがあるので、ライブラリ化したものがあったら教えていただきたいです。

さらにラスターの２次元画像を与えたときに境界ベクター情報（線画）にして抽出するようなフリーライブラリはないでしょうか。
これができれば抽出できる属性にバリエーションが増えそうなので。

言語は Java, Ruby, PHP, JavaScript あたりをよく使うのでこの中だとうれしいですが、AI だと Python が多いみたいなので Python でも大丈夫です。

以上２点よろしくおねがいします。